# Why some deeds are experienced in hell and heaven and some in earth?

Tags: dharma, rebirth

- We will go to heaven for our dharma activities and hell for adharma activities and experience them for a while.
- Affter that we will take birth and experience a life also according to the dharma and adharma

**QUESTION** :

- Which some deeds are experienced in heaven and hell and why some are in earth ?

Comment: Related [How can heaven-hell concept and rebirth concept both be true?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3344/3500)

Comment: @TheDestroyer But it says if we do very high bad deeds we will go to hell and very high good deeds we will go to heaven and small good and bad deeds to take birth in earth but in our day to day life you can see people suffering tortures very worse like no food,beatings like slave and importantly many good women loose their virginity by guys of kama thinking and marriage very worst drunk guys and even worse that cannot be said so how to solve this problem as 70 or 60 years tortues better ?

Comment: Hells only appear in the Puranas as punishments. The Upanishads only mention rebirth in lower forms on earth. If you think of hells then to hells you will go. Think of God and to God you will go. Gita 18.58, 18.62, 18.65-66

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda So you mean to say other lokas don't exist at all? Then what about Rasatala, Talatala, Patala?

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria If you believe in Rasatala, and Talatala, and Patala, then to those heavens you shall go.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda It's not about believing or not believing, these hellish planets do exist in Hiranyagarbha, don't they?

Answer (score 1):

First of all in order to Undergo Karma there has to be a medium, example you can not see without eyes, So it means **in order to undergo karma there has to be the medium of physical Body**

Hell and Heaven are in your chitt(mind), not somewhere else on other planet.

Some atma has to come back even from Moksha to undergo some Karma.

The entire process of how karma works can never be known to humans.

**All we know is by performing good karmas, one is practicing the purity of mind, because only a pure mind can become peaceful.**

What we should learn from this Question is **if something bad happens to us, show gratitude and ask god to give us strength to undergo this result of negative Karma.**

Now the question arises should we pray only in bad times?  No we should pray daily because Lord Krishna says in Gita "one perform karma every moment, even if one is sitting idle" and **by repeating a prayer(thought) over and over again our intellect will become sharp and pure, which leads to pure and controlled mind, and in the end a state of tranquility can be attained.**