# Is there a permanent hell?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, dharma, advaita, dharma-shastras

Madhvas believe in eternal hell, but what is the standard view (before the rise of Dvaita Vedanta)?

If not, are souls that do not attain Moksha eternally trapped in this cycle of countless births and deaths, and hells and heaven?

Comment: This view is only peculiar to Madhvacharya.

Comment: @Ikshvaku what do Shri Vaishnavas believe?

Comment: We believe hell is temporary, just as the shastras say: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31538/11726