# Why are we getting punished in hell?

Tags: astrology

According to astrologers, each and every second of incidents of a person takes place according to his planetary positions.

If that is the case, we do bad and good actions, that is also caused by the planetary positions.

So, why are we punished in hell if our actions are corresponding to planets and not on our own?

Comment: 1. We get hell for our ignorance, for bad karmas we get lower life. Hell is punishment of ignorance not bad karmas. 2. Planets are in accordance of your results of your past actions. Such configuration of planets are due to your past karmas not planets.

Comment: Ignorance of what?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18421/8696

Comment: But you urself have earned those planetary positions in the current life by doing some or the the karmas in ur previous lives. So, who else other than you is responsible here? NONE.

Comment: @Rickross Lets suppose that I do something bad in my 1st incarnation, so because of that I will get a bad planetary position in my second incarnation. because of that bad position, I will again compelled to do bad action in my 2nd incarnation. Because of my bad action in 2nd incarnation also, I will get bad planet position in 3rd incarnation and do bad. Does that mean once bad always bad?

Comment: Yes that's more r less True. One bad karma produces an infinite chain of bad karmas. But u must be doing some good karmas too, then those will initiate infinite chains of good karmas too..so the results will be mixed..  That's why we all have some benefic planetary combinations and some malefic too in our birth charts..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we need Yamalokam?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/363/why-do-we-need-yamalokam)

Comment: True...Every incident came to anyone's life according to there planetary position. But, how the person deals the incident is totally depends upon the person. Let suppose, if you are in a situation of 'Yes' or 'No', the situation may be caused by your planetary position but it's you who chooses either one of them (Yes or No). Your decision may be wrong or right, if your decision is right then it will become your good Karma or bad if it's wrong. So, what you make of your actions (Good or Bad) is your Karma.

Comment: Suppose in a exam u got 20%. Obviously u failed. U failed not because of 20%. U failed because ur exam were bad. 20% is just showing ur situation. Similarly ur planetary position r the result ( just like %) of ur previous births. Ur present action are determined not because of planetary position but because of ur previous birth's karma. Ur planetary position just showing how much good or bad will be ur present birth's karma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the assumption that every moment is determined by planetary positions. To extend further, planetary positions themselves are also predetermined within universe. So all we do & experience is destiny. Hence, there is [no existence of free will](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10911/1049).

One suffers in hell or enjoys in heaven due to those planetary positions or destiny.
Q: How is such suffering justified?
A: The philosophical reason is: **We(our consciousness) want the suffering [& enjoyment]**.

> BG 13.22 - *Purusha* being seated(situated) in *Prakruti*, experiences the [*sattva, rajas, tamas*] modes born of *Prakruti*. **Contact with the these modes, is the cause of its births in good and evil wombs**.

Let's take an Example:

- Consider, audience as "Purusha" (enjoyer/witness/consumer). Consider movie as "Prakruti" and all the emotional aspects in a movie as 3 modes of "Prakruti".
- Why do we see a horror movie -- to get horrified, tragic movie -- to get pained, comic movie -- for amusement. Similarly, the so called punishment in hell or rewards in heaven are all categorised under "enjoyment" (or "consumption") for the *Purusha*.
- The movie playing in front of the audience is already shoot in reels & hence predetermined. Similarly one's births and actions are also destined.
- The movie won't change its course depending on audience's mood. Same as *Prakruti* won't change its destiny depending on *Purusha*.

---

When audience gets "bored" of movie regardless of its sad/funny/romantic emotions, they leave theatre in between. Exactly same, when *Purusha* becomes indifferent to the *Prakruti*, it gets realised & then liberated. In either cases, there is [no purpose left, to continue](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20243/1049).

When the movie gets over, everyone has to leave the theatre. Exactly same, when the *Prakruti*'s cycle finishes, all are liberated (see the combined meaning of BG 9.7 & BG 14.2).

Comment: The analogy of theatre and movie is great sir. But who exactly is the director  and producer of this film?

Comment: @KawinM, it's just an analogy to understand the concept. The complete movie creation happens under *Prakruti*, so you may consider that as a producer & director. :-) BTW, both *Purusha* & *Prakruti* are part of *Atma* (formless *Brahman*), which Krishna also referred as "Me".